# Can't set primary key and foreign key on one column

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, data-annotations

So I try to create some ASP.NET project with EF Core.

I want to set propert of one entity as primary key and foreign key to another entity. The relationship is `0..1 - 1`. I use `DataAnnotations`:

```
public class OfficeAssignment
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("InstructorID")]
    public int InstructorID { get; set; }
    public Instructor Instructor { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

But I keep getting column `InstructorID` as PK and `InstructorID1` as FK... Any ideas, why EF behaves like that and how can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Doesn't make much sense for the primary key to also be a foreign key. Add a dedicated foreign key column if you can.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this doesn't work in Entity Framework because of related entities/navigation properties

Comment: @DanWilson It makes perfect sense for a 1 to 0..1 relation which is exactly what the OP wants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should follow convention over configuration as much as you can. An `OfficeAssignment` entity should have an `OfficeAssignmentId` PK, like this:

```
public class OfficeAssignment
{
    public int OfficeAssignmentId { get; set; }

    //Notice that Id does not have an uppercase D
    public int InstructorId { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }

    public Instructor Instructor { get; set; }
}
```

However, if you don't want to follow normal conventions, the name of the property that goes in the `ForeignKey` attribute is the opposite of where it's declared:

```
public class OfficeAssignment
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Instructor")]
    public int InstructorId { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }

    public Instructor Instructor { get; set; }
}
```

And, if you want to keep it compile-time safe:

```
public class OfficeAssignment
{
    [Key, ForeignKey(nameof(Instructor))]
    public int InstructorId { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }

    public Instructor Instructor { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Oh my... It was enough to read description of `ForeignKey` attribute constructor...

Comment: @MichałTurczyn Yeah, that's happened to me before

Answer (score 0):

It's enough to set primary key attribute(`[Key]`) in the `OfficeAssignment` class and in `Instructor` class we need to set such attribute:

```
[InverseProperty("Instructor")]
```

on collection of `CourseAssignments`. That will work as desired.